# Oracle use temporary table or some other method

Tags: oracle, temp-tables

In Oracle, Need to re-use results of a query multiple times in a stored proc. Wondering if temp table is the recommended way or something else...

First I create a resultset based on certain input params.

Then do some checks to see if any of the resultset rows appear in Table 1. Simple join and count would suffice.
If count > 0 then return.
If count == 0 then I insert selected values from resultset  (based on some condition) to Table 1.

Should one go with temp table or something else for optimal performance?

Thanks,

Comment: Thanks N. Kaufman.   A little more information would be helpful-- after inserting into Table 1, do you then go on to further re-use the query-results again?   From what is described, it only looks like one use.  If you are only conditionally inserting into one table, PLSQL may not be required at all ( at least not for the insert-if-not-present); a conditional `INSERT`, or a `MERGE` might be enough.  Also how much data are you dealing with? Is this hundreds/thousands, or millions (have you tried just keeping it in memory?)

Comment: Absolutely, thanks for responding. 

I first use the result set (that is a complex and a bit expensive query and hence want to store the result) to compare if data exists in Table 1. This is use # 1.

If not then I insert into Table 1, selected rows from this result set. Isn't this use#2? 

Thanks again.

Comment: After this, I'll be doing some more inserts etc. (but not using this resultset) in my procedure.

Data would be no more than 20 rows but query to get them is complex and expensive. Please let me know if I've explained the issue properly.

Thanks again.

Comment: Thanks N. Kaufman.  I'd just been referring to the notion that one can check for matches and apply conditions to the insert all within one sql statement.  Testing and benchmarking is always the best way to tell, but at a glance, I'd imagine that a temp table would not be necessary (though it could work too, good to benchmark).  One could keep these in memory in the procedure, or just do a conditional insert.  I'll add some examples of these approaches, though there are probably other ways.

Comment: I looked at my scenario and found that i'll be inserting data from resultset to 2 tables based on certain conditions. So, if I have 20 rows in my resultset, after confirming that nothing exists in Table1, I'll insert a few in Table1 and the rest in Table2

Answer (score 1):

In light of the last update, it appears that you'll need to make qualitatively different inserts into multiple tables, and use the result of an expensive query in multiple (different) tests.

It is always best to test and benchmark (comparing the upsides and downsides, along with performance of the temp table vs other approaches).  I'll include an alternative style here, that just pulls the results into memory, where they can be queried against as needed (or iterated-over, counted, etc.)

An example is below:

-- Example Data:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_1 (LOREM_IPSUM NUMBER);
INSERT INTO TABLE_1 VALUES (6);
COMMIT;
```

-- Custom Types to hold the data

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EXPENSIVE_QUERY_TYPE IS OBJECT(LOREM_IPSUM NUMBER);
/
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE EXPENSIVE_QUERY_RESULT IS TABLE OF EXPENSIVE_QUERY_TYPE;
/
```

-- Example block:

```
DECLARE
    V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT EXPENSIVE_QUERY_RESULT := EXPENSIVE_QUERY_RESULT();
    V_TABLE_1_TEST INTEGER;
BEGIN
    SELECT EXPENSIVE_QUERY_TYPE(LEVEL)
    BULK COLLECT INTO V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT
    FROM DUAL
    CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5;

    SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_TABLE_1_TEST
        FROM TABLE_1
            WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM TABLE(V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT) WHERE LOREM_IPSUM = TABLE_1.LOREM_IPSUM);

    IF V_TABLE_1_TEST > 0
        THEN
        RETURN;
        ELSE
        INSERT INTO TABLE_1
            SELECT LOREM_IPSUM FROM TABLE(V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT)
            WHERE MOD(LOREM_IPSUM,2) = 0;
    END IF;

END;
/
```

When TABLE_1 initially has only a single record of value 6, this inserts 2 and 4 (since there are no shared data).

```
...PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1;
   LOREM_IPSUM
______________
             2
             4
             6
```

But if it includes anything in the expensive_query (such as initially including both 3 and 6), nothing is inserted:

```
...PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1;
   LOREM_IPSUM
______________
             3
             6
```

Comment: Thanks N. Kaufman for the update.  In response, I've dropped the 2nd example (using a single statement) from this answer.  Thanks

Comment: Thank you for this.. Might take me a while to understand this...
EXPENSIVE_QUERY_TYPE IS OBJECT(LOREM_IPSUM NUMBER) - assuming that the params are going to be my params of my expensive query. So if my query returns FirstName, LastName, Salary, my object is 
EXPENSIVE_QUERY_TYPE IS OBJECT(fn varchar(50), ln varchar(50), sal number).

How do I fill V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT with my 'expensive' query - Select fname, lname, salary from emp where salary > 12000. 

Insert into V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT(fname, lname, salary) select Select fname, lname, salary from emp where salary > 12000??

Comment: Thanks @N.Kaufman Yeah the object type in this kind of approach would match the shape of the `expensive_query` header.  If that is fname/lname/salary, the example type-definition you provided looks good.  As for loading it, two pieces are involved -- SELECTing the object-type and BULK COLLECTing into the table-type.  Here's a distilled syntax SELECT EXPENSIVE_QUERY_TYPE(FNAME, LNAME, SALARY) BULK COLLECT INTO V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT FROM ... JOIN ... WHERE ...;  If any issues or follow-up just let me know.  I'd also be interested in any follow-up on performance comparisons with temp table et al.

Comment: thank you for your assistance and patience.still trying to wrap my head around selecting object type.
If my query is Select fname, lname, salary from emp join sal on emp.dept = sal.dept where sal.salary > 12000, what would my bulk collect query be?

SELECT EXPENSIVE_QUERY_TYPE(FNAME, LNAME, SALARY) BULK COLLECT INTO V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT FROM emp join sal on emp.dept = sal.dept where sal.salary > 12000.

Did I get that??

Comment: Thanks @N.Kaufman Provided those tables and join, that bulk collect looks good (though joining emp to sal via dept seems unusual).   The query should compile ok(all else aside) and be usable in later selects via SELECT FNAME, LNAME, SAL FROM TABLE(V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT) .  Thanks

Comment: Thanks for your comments.. 
The query is just something I pulled out of thin air as an example, for my own understanding... It has nothing to do with actual query...

Also, can we do the following instead:
SELECT COUNT(*) INTO V_TABLE_1_TEST
        FROM TABLE_1 a
        inner join TABLE(V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT) b on b.LOREM_IPSUM = a.LOREM_IPSUM;

Comment: Hello - The following statement needs a Connect BY clause..:
SELECT EXPENSIVE_QUERY_TYPE(FNAME, LNAME, SALARY) BULK COLLECT INTO V_EXPENSIVE_RESULT FROM emp join sal on emp.dept = sal.dept where sal.salary > 12000
What would that be?

Comment: Thanks @N.Kaufman The `CONNECT BY` in my example is just part of a stand-in query for this example in the place your expensive query would go--just a throwaway query to create a few rows and demonstrate the structure.  I just wanted to show selecting into a collection of objects with expensive-query structure instead of a temp table.  The object, query + bulk collect would need to be adapted to your situation.  Thanks